# TCP/IP API in Jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter, tcp

Can anyone please help on creating the TCP/IP API in Jmeter for the automation and load testing.

Below is the API call need to hit on Ip - 10.10.xx.xxx on port 4433

How to put these call in Jmeter for the scripting.

> {
>   \"COMM_DAILY_TXN_LIMIT\":\"000001500000\",
>   \"COMM_MONTHLY_LIMIT_FLAG\":\"1\",
>   \"COMM_CODE_USD\":\"0\",
>   \"COMM_MER_TYPE\":\"\",
>   \"MCHIP_FLAG\":\"1\",
>   \"COMM_COD_POSTAL\":\"400001\",
>   \"MASTER_TRMN_TYPE\":\"0\",
>   \"RRN\":\"200\",
>   \"COMM_MONTHLY_LIMIT\":\"000015000000\",
>   \"TERMINAL_NUM\":\"0006019A\",
>   \"MONTHLY_TXN_LIMIT\":\"000015000000\",
>   \"COMM_KEY_ENTRY\":\"1\",
>   \"COMM_NUM_FAX\":\"9930197345\",
>   \"VSDC_FLAG\":\"1\",
>   \"TYPE\":\"3\",
>   \"PER_TXN_LIMIT_FLAG\":\"1\",
>   \"MASTERCARD_PAN\":\"\",
>   \"REQTYPE\":\"200\",
>   \"DEVICE_TYPE\":\"0\",
>   \"MONTHLY_LIMIT_UPD_FLAG\":\"1\",
>   \"COMM_ENSEIGNE\":\"VENK FINAL DBA\",
>   \"REQDT\":\"15052018110916\",
>   \"COMM_CODE_CATEG\":\"7011\",
>   \"MOBILE_NO\":\"\",
>   \"CAM_RELIABILITY_INDICATR\":\"1\",
>   \"COMM_NUM_COMM\":\"0450000A0000716\",
>   \"COMM_CODE_AG\":\"00045               \",
>   \"COMM_PER_TXN_LIMIT\":\"000000100000\",
>   \"CODE_MONNAIE\":\"356\",\"COMM_DAILY_LIMIT_UPD_FLAG\":\"1\",
>   \"COMM_INSTITUTION_FLAG\":\"0\",
>   \"RUPAY_PAN\":\"\",
>   \"COMM_TYPE_COMM\":\"S\",
>   \"TERMINAL_TYPE\":\"M\",
>   \"COMM_CODE_ANNUL\":\"1\",
>   \"DAILY_TXN_LIMIT\":\"000001500000\",
>   \"COMM_LOCALIS\":\"MUMBAI\",
>   \"COMM_INTR_BIN_FLAG\":\"0\",
>   \"VISA_PAN\":\"\",
>   \"DAILY_LIMIT_UPD_FLAG\":\"1\",
>   \"COMM_LIGNE1\":\"VENK FINAL LEGAL\",
>   \"COMM_PER_TXN_LIMIT_FLAG\":\"1\",
>   \"COMM_CODE_BNQ\":\"00045\",
>   \"COMM_TIER\":\"0\",
>   \"COMM_CODE_ECOMMERCE\":\"0\",
>   \"COMM_LIGNE2\":\"VENK FINAL LEGAL\",
>   \"PER_TXN_LIMIT\":\"000000100000\",
>   \"MOBILE_NO1\":\"\",
>   \"COMM_COD_PAYS\":\"356\",
>   \"MOBILE_NO4\":\"\",
>   \"MOBILE_NO5\":\"\",
>   \"MOBILE_NO2\":\"\",
>   \"PIN_ENCRYPTION_TYPE\":\"1\",
>   \"SPECIAL_KEY_ENTRY\":\"1\",
>   \"AMEX_MID\":\"\",
>   \"MOBILE_NO3\":\"\",
>   \"USER\":\"MRLPAY\",
>   \"PAYWAVE_PAYPASS_FLAG\":\"0\",
>   \"COMM_ADRES1\":\"202AVANMALI\",
>   \"ACTION\":\"C\",
>   \"BANKCODE\":\"00045\",
>   \"COMM_ONLY_CASH_AT_POS_FLAG\":\"0\",
>   \"COMM_ADRES2\":\"VKPATILMARG\",
>   \"COMM_ADRES3\":\"VKPATILMARG\",
>   \"ACTIVITY\":\"1\",
>   \"LINE_ENCRYPT_TERM\":\"4\",
>   \"COMM_IRD_FLAG\":\"0\"
>   }

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to your Test Plan
2. Put `10.10.xx.xxx` into "Server Name or IP" input
3. Put `4443` into "Port Number"

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request]
4. Most probably you will need to type `https` into "Protocol"
5. Most probably you will need to change "Method" to `POST`
6. Most probably you will need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

   [image: JMeter HTTP Header Manager]

Refer to [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) article if you need more information.

Comment: how to convert the java program to jmx file for the load testing

Comment: Help on creating the JMX file for below code ISO packet for load testing

MTI [ 0220 ]
DE[3]: 200001
DE[4]: 000000050000
DE[11]: 000112
DE[12]: 235847
DE[13]: 0209
DE[22]: 021
DE[24]: 394
DE[25]: 00
DE[35]: 7034811000000002163d129950009999258f
DE[38]: 602827
DE[41]: 00100222
DE[42]: 062022079000151
DE[52]: 1234
DE[61]: 000005
DE[62]: 001
DE[63]: 042002010020020403400882770573043006123456